# Using jQuery delegate() to replace live()

Tags: jquery, jquery-delegate

I currently am creating content using jQuery.

`Live()`, according to the jQuery API Description: *Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.*.  I need this line of code to work in the future.

`$(".trash").delegate('.delete_gallery', 'click', function(event) {` // does not work
`$(".delete_gallery").live("click", function(event) {` // works

How can I get the delegate to work?  I don't want to use a deprecated function.

`.on()` is not a choice.  Hopefully this isn't a duplicate question either, I couldn't find any that addressed this, they all just say how to do it.

Thanks!
Jacob

Comment: Why is `.on()` not an option?

Comment: Just a sanity check, but is .delete_gallery a child of .trash?

Comment: @ethagnawl, yes, and Austin, I can't control what version of jQuery the plugin users are using.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621057/jquerys-delegate-parameter-order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be better delegating the event handler to $(document) rather than $(".trash') as it means you're not relying on it existing.

Comment: Can you clarify on this, as this actually fixed it.  .delete_gallery was a direct child of .trash, so I assumed it would be better to be more direct.

Comment: @Jacob, your `.trash` elements are probably dynamic. Event delegation works by binding events on *non-dynamic* ancestors to your dynamic content. `document` works because it's the root of the DOM tree and, as such, always static.

Comment: That would seem to be the case.  Thank you! Selecting this answer as it holds the reason why.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$(document).delegate('.delete_gallery', 'click', function(event) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You still have `.bind()`.

**Example**

```
$(".trash").bind('click', function(event) {
```

Comment: `.bind()` only works on preexisting elements, and not any in the future